# self class to initialize controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I stuck with a problem with converting code from obj-c.

```
controller = [[[self class] alloc] initWithNibName:name bundle:nil];
```

I have tried something like this

```
self.init(nibName: name, bundle: nil)
```

But it gives me an error: **Constructing an object of class type 'BaseViewController' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer**.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As Ronak pointed out you need to add the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` method. In addition to it you need to add the `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)` method too. So your overall code will look something like this:

```
  class func customInitializer() -> ViewController {
    return self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add initializer method in your VC like below:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Also check out here:

http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/08/initializing-view-controllers-in-swift.html

Hope it will help:)